# Escaping in nested substitute() command results in ^@ characters in 7.2

Tags: regex, vim, escaping, substitution

I've got a document:

```
"""I'm a multiline string.
I say 
  "hey, single line string", 
and it says 
  "\they, multiline string,\nI can do multiple lines\ntoo".
and I say, 
  "it's cute that you think you can".

Yeah, I'm kind of a jerk."""
```

I can use a nested `substitute()` to transform it:

```
:%s/"""\(\_.\{-}\)"""/\='"'.substitute(submatch(1),'["\\\n]','\\\0','g').'"'/g
```

In vim 7.3, I get what I'm trying for:

```
"I'm a multiline string.\
I say \
  \"hey, single line string\", \
and it says \
  \"\\they, multiline string,\\nI can do multiple lines\\ntoo\".\
and I say, \
  \"it's cute that you think you can\".\
\
Yeah, I'm kind of a jerk."
```

However, in vim 7.2, I get a different result for the same input and command:

```
"I'm a multiline string.^@I say ^@  "hey, single line string", ^@and it says ^@ "\they, multiline string,\nI can do multiple lines\ntoo".^@and I say, ^@  "it's cute that you think you can".^@^@Yeah, I'm kind of a jerk."
```

(Where `^@` is, as far as I can tell, a zero byte).

Why am I getting such vastly different behaviour? How should I modify my `:%s` command to have the same effect in both 7.2 and 7.3?

Comment: I don't know vim at all but it could have an issue with the `\0`, try using something else instead. Maybe you can try `$0` or `$&`.

Comment: I do not have access to 7.2. Only 7.3 and 7.0. I can get the following to work in 7.0: `:%s/"""\(\_.\{-}\)"""/\=escape(substitute(submatch(1),'["\\\n]','\\&', 'g'),'\')/g`. In 7.3 you can simplify your command to: `%s/"""\(\_.\{-}\)"""/\=escape(submatch(1),"\n\"\\")/g`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the behavior you're experiencing is due to the bug fixed by patch 7.3.225:

> "\n" in a substitute() inside ":s" not handled correctly

Vim 7.2 is from 2008 and *very* outdated. It should be possible to install the latest version 7.3; if you can't find a proper package for your distribution (for Windows, check the binaries from the [Cream project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cream/files/Vim/), it's also not very difficult to [compile](http://www.vim.org/download.php) (e.g. from the Mercurial sources) on Linux.

If you do need to support older Vim versions and you find a workaround, you can implement a conditional:

```
if v:version > 703 || v:version == 703 && has('patch225')
    " new implementation
else
    " workaround
endif
```